# Method OnSensorChanged() when screen is lock

Tags: android, sensors

On my Samsung Galaxy S 2 I have the known bug when OnSensorChanged() method does not call when screen is lock (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3708 ). Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You solve the problem by getting a partial wake lock from the power manager which keeps the CPU from sleeping when the screen goes off.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock lock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "SensorRead");
lock.acquire();
```

Make sure to release it when you are done so you don't drain the battery.

You need this permission in your manifest too:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```